# implementing recurring subscription in paypal making trouble , not able to get profileid in response

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring

I have two queries 
1> i 'm trying to implement recurring subscription by firing this url => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick-subscriptions&business=soumik10@yahoo.co.in&item_name=subscriptiontrack¤cy_code=USD&
a3=10&t3=M&p3=1&custom=mydata&invoice=9830722410

I'm able to do that but the problem that making me sick is that the " response is not sending profileid " , as i need it to cancel subscription .

or if there is any other way to get profileid from any other api please provide me that api url

2> how to get a subscription details from a subscriptionid , i guess i f i can do that from there i will get profile id.

please guide me I need this help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved , I contacted with paypal technical support  , they said that they are working on paypalpro modules , and it was not working  at that time , but now they have fixed  it , only you need to have  a merchant id with Business pro  account and with US profile . I hope this helps other guys . Now ican use dodirect payment api for credit transaction . I have tested the above given url with new sandbox mechant id with business pro enabled and having US. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). It will be part of the message sent to your server. eg:

```
&subscr_id=I-UDUWCJ0XETNF &custom=mydata &payer_status=verified &business=
```

Comment: Yes I'm using IPN . and i do get " &subscr_id=I-UDUWCJ0XETNF &custom=mydata &payer_status=verified &business= " this type of responses . Does "subscr_id" and profileid are same . If same then why it is not working  . Actually  i need to find the subscription status , to track whether it has been cancelled or not so I'm usinng this url to check https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails
    &USER=soumik10_api1.yahoo.co.in&PWD=1401520404&SIGNATURE=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AmWfDfsaKco4X7iAvZ0ed2jFrfuN&VERSION=85.0&PROFILEID=I-NBP2LXXS0VEE

Comment: This is because you cannot use that API call for Subscriptions. It is reserved for profiles created using `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` API. If you passed `&VERSION=98` in that string you should also get back a result saying this: **[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Subscription Profiles not supported by Recurring Payment APIs.**

Comment: If that is so then how i'm going to check programmitically my users subscription status , whether they have cancelled it or not. I need a way to check it . Please tell  me the way , i need help,

Comment: You need to use the API to create the subscription with `SetExpressCheckout` and `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` any current subscriptions would not be able to be managed via the API.